# How to change msal authority in runtime?

Tags: angular7, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

## Background:

I have an angular 7 app.
The app authenticates using Azure Active Directory B2C and Msal for angular

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular

I have created 2 user flow's in AAD B2C:

1. Signin flow V2
2. Signup flow V2

both have UI customized,

both contain a redirect button to the other AAD B2C flow.

(from register -> login | from login -> register)

I have setup MSAL module in angular, with Signin flow as the default authority
e.g

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
...,
authority: <"https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/tfp/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Signin">,
...
})
```

(notice **B2C_1_Signin** flow name)

This is working well, user can login and register (navigate between flows from within a flow and authenticate).

## Problem:

The problem start when I try to manually change the MSAL module authority 
(that was defined in MSAL init as B2C_1_Signin flow when app starts).

Example:
User get to a welcome page and can click Login / Register.
If the user clicks login,all is well because the authority link was defined at start as Signin flow (**B2C_1_Signin**).

If the user would like to register,
I need to change the authority link
to the selected AAD flow (**B2C_1_Signup**) and then I call MSAL loginRedirect(), user get redirects to right AAD flow, enter his details and redirect back to the app.
Then the app will start a new login flow and redirects to the login flow **as if the user is not authenticated**.

This only happens when I change the authority link manually (I have no other choice in order to navigate to right flow).
Otherwise, all is working as expected.

How should I change the authority, so the app will not fail the user authentication?

- I have tried using default AAD Signup v1 flow with no customization.
- I have tried to reveres the process in order to isolate the problem (setup Signup flow as default,
  change authority manually to Signin flow, same error (as expected).
- I have searched many different sites and forums but none have the same issue or a fix.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/498

https://medium.com/@sambowenhughes/configuring-your-angular-6-application-to-use-microsoft-b2c-authentication-99a9ff1403b3

and many more...

MSAL for angular setup:
"authentication.module.ts"

```
MsalModule.forRoot({

      clientID: "<my-client-id>",

      authority: "https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tfp/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Signin",

      redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/dashboard",

      /* default is true */
      validateAuthority: false, 

      /* Defaults is 'sessionStorage' */
      cacheLocation : "localStorage", 

      /* Defaults is 'redirectUri */      
      postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/", 

      /* Ability to turn off default navigation to start page after login. Default is true. */
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl : false, 

      /* Show login popup or redirect. Default:Redirect */
      popUp: false,            
    })
```

AuthService wrapping MSAL auth service:
"auth.service.ts"

```
constructor(private msalService: MsalService) {}

public login(scopes: string[] = null, queryParams: string = null): void {    

    this.msalService.authority = this.tenantConfig.baseURL + "/" + this.tenantConfig.tenant + "/" + this.tenantConfig.signInPolicy;

    this.msalService.loginRedirect(scopes, queryParams);
  }

public signup(scopes: string[] = null, queryParams: string = null): void {    

    this.msalService.authority = this.tenantConfig.baseURL + "/" + this.tenantConfig.tenant + "/" + this.tenantConfig.signUpPolicy;
    this.msalService.loginRedirect(scopes, queryParams);
  }
```

I expect the Msal module to work as usual even if I change the initial defined authority.

Comment: Have you tried submitting an issue against the MSAL GitHub library? The issues section for MSAL.JS can be found here : https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues

There's actually an ongoing issue on trying to change authority during runtime per the issue here : https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/784

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried submitting an issue against the MSAL GitHub library? The issues section for MSAL.JS can be found here : https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues

There's actually an ongoing issue on trying to change authority during runtime per the issue here : https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/784

As it's not exactly the same, I suggest filing a new github issue. However it looks like this is not a supported feature as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem with our application.  The fix was essentially turning off MFA.

If MFA is turned on for sign-in, switching from sign-up to sign-in wasn't giving us an MFA prompt and unceremoniously did not authorize the user to be signed in.

Our solution was to detect if the sign in was attempting directly after a sign up and have a non-MFA sign in flow for that case specifically.  Not sure if you're doing MFA, but if you are it's worth a look.